# DocumentDB client lifetime

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, lifetime-scoping

To access DocumentDB/CosmosDB I'm using package `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`(v1.3.2). I have noticed when I create and initialise `DocumentClient` class:

```
var documentClient = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), primaryKey);
await documentClient.OpenAsync();
```

There is a number of requests fired to the endpoint to get information about indexes and other information. To be exact there are 9 HTTP requests going out on `.OpenAsync()`. This makes the creation and activation of the client a very costly operation in terms of performance - takes up to a second to get all the requests back home.

So to mitigate this costly operation I'm making `DocumentClient` to be a singleton and keep the reference around for the lifetime of the application.

Application is Asp.Net Core MVC and this might keep the reference of this object in memory for days.

**Question:** is it OK to keep this object as a singleton for that long? if not, what should be the strategy to dispose it? Or is there a way to make the initialisation cheaper (i.e. don't make these initial requests?).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We've wondered that for ourselves as well and found this:

From the [docs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/performance-tips-for-azure-documentdb-part-1-2/)

> **SDK Usage Tip #1:** Use a singleton DocumentDB client for the lifetime of your application Note that each DocumentClient instance is thread-safe and performs efficient connection management and address caching when operating in Direct Mode. To allow efficient connection management and better performance by DocumentClient, it is recommended to use a single instance of DocumentClient per AppDomain for the lifetime of the application.

I suppose this is still valid now you can address CosmosDB with it as well.

Comment: Thank you! I've missed this article. Singleton it is!